# Оформлено верно? Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

**Работа будет оцениваться по системе зачёт — незачёт**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наиболее приемлемой формой является следующая запись:  *Работа будет оцениваться **по системе «зачёт — незачёт».***

Например: *О внедрении в школах системы «зачет — незачет.»*

В то же время встречаются и другие варианты: дефис, косая черта, запись без кавычек. Все они имеют определенное обоснование.

**ТИРЕ**   http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108.

Тире ставится между нарицательными именами существительными, сочетание которых выполняет **определительную функцию при имени существительном**: Система человек — машина; Отношения учитель — ученик; Проблема рыночные отношения — социальная справедливость. Число сочетающихся имен может быть и больше двух: Проблема производство — человек — природа; Статья В. А. Сухомлинского «Педагог — коллектив — личность».

**КАВЫЧКИ**
Использование кавычек более предпочтительно, так как это не просто определение при существительном, но и название системы.

ХАРАКТЕРИСТИКА ДРУГИХ ЗНАКОВ

**КОСАЯ ЧЕРТА**  http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=60#pp60

§ 114. Сфера применения знака / (косая черта) — научная и деловая речь. Он употребляется в следующих функциях.

1. В функции, близкой к союзам и и или, как знак альтернативности понятий или обозначения единого сложного понятия, напр.: категория одушевлённости/неодушевлённости, проблема слитных/раздельных написаний (в лингвистических текстах);  В этой функции может употребляться не только косая черта, но и дефис (см. § 120, п. 1а).

**ДЕФИС**  http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp120.ph

§ 120. Следующие разряды существительных и сочетания существительных пишутся через дефис

1. Сочетания двух существительных, в которых первая часть обладает самостоятельным склонением:
   а) сочетания-повторы разного типа, парные конструкции, сочетания соотносительных или близких по значению слов, напр.: умница-разумница, друг-приятель, имя-отчество, купля продажа, марксизм-ленинизм.

Answer (score 3):

> Отметок не будет ― только зачёт-незачёт; и вузам его учитывать будет
> не обязательно (при, говорят, обязательности учёта сдачи норм ГТО!
> [Александр Привалов. О неизбежных последствиях // «Эксперт», 2014]
>
> "Мы проводим испытание не по принципу «зачет-незачет», а чтобы
> получить новое знание", ― утверждал генерал. [Андрей Лебедев.
> Невооруженным глазом. США делают еще один шаг к созданию национальной
> системы ПРО // «Известия», 2001.12.02]

Тип отметок «зачёт-незачёт» согласно принятым системам (формулам, схемам, правилам) следует выделять в тексте при наличии родового слова. О дефисе: *зачёт-незачёт* не предусматривает промежуточных оценок, что дефисом, в отличие от тире, ясно фиксируется.

Некоторые, чаще канцелярские тексты, не прибегают к выделению и используют прямой (обычный) слеш:

> Текущая аттестация обеспечивает оперативное управление учебной
> деятельностью... словесно-объяснительно, в виде отметок по
> пятибалльной шкале или в виде системы зачет/незачет.